# How is the return statement working, What is the logic behind it?

Tags: python

I have a doubt in the return statement. Return statement is calling dfs function using and operator, so is dfs function called twice?

```
class Solution:
    def isEscapePossible(self, blocked, source, target):
        if not blocked:
            return True

        n = len(blocked)

        def dfs(start,end,visited):
            stack = [start]

            while stack:
                i, j = stack.pop(0)

                if abs(start[0]-i) + abs(start[1]-j) >= n or [i,j] == end:
                    return True

                for ni,nj in [(i-1,j),(i+1,j),(i,j-1),(i,j+1)]:
                    if 0 <= ni < 10**6 and 0 <= nj < 10**6 and [ni,nj] not in blocked and (ni,nj) not in visited:
                        stack.append((ni,nj))
                        visited.add((ni,nj))

            return False

        return dfs(source,target,set(source)) and dfs(target,source,set(target))
```

Comment: Where in your code do you see a recursive call?

Comment: Your title questions are too broad. If you explain what specific problem you're trying to solve maybe we can help.

Comment: `dfs` is called once or twice, depending on the result of the first call. This is because "`and`" is a bit of a special operator. The left `dfs` is called; if the result is True, then the right `dfs` is called too. But if the first `dfs` results in False, then the second `dfs` is not called.

Comment: I had to post my answer as a comment because your question was closed on the grounds of "lacking details or clarity", even though it was perfectly clear and didn't lack any details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those `set(source)` and `set(target)` calls are not correct, but I'm not certain I understand what they're trying to do, really. Maybe `{source}` and `{target}`? In any case, this is mostly irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be executed twice. `and` is part of the expression given to the return statement, equivalent to

```
return (... and ...)
```

not

```
(return ...) and ...
```

There are potentially two calls to `dfs`: `dfs(source, target, set(source)` is always called, and if it returns `True`, `dfs(target,source,set(target))` is called to determine the value of the `and` expression. If the first call returns `False`, the second call is skipped; its value is not needed because `False and ...` is always `False`, no matter what the second argument is.

Answer (score 1):

`dfs` is called once or twice, depending on the result of the first call. This is because "`and`" is a bit of a special operator. We say `and` is ***lazy***.

The left `dfs` is called; if the result is True, then the right `dfs` is called too. But if the first `dfs` results in False, then the second `dfs` is not called.

In other words, the return statement is equivalent to this:

```py
b1 = dfs(source,target,set(source))
if not b1:
    return b1
else:
    b2 = dfs(target,source,set(target))
    return b2
```